# Solution to Euler Project Task 5: Why does it work?

Tags: python, optimization

After some trial and error I have found a solution which works very quickly for the [Project Euler Problem 5](https://projecteuler.net/problem=5). (I have found another way which correctly solved the example case (numbers 1-10) but took an eternity to solve the actual Problem.) Here it goes:

```
def test(n):
    for x in range(2,21):
        if n % x != 0:
            return False
    return True

def thwart(n):
    for x in range(2,21):
        if test(n/x):
            n /= x
            return n
    raise TypeError

num = 1
for x in range(1,21):
    num *= x

while True:
    try:
        num = thwart(num)
    except TypeError:
        break


print(num)
```

My main problem is understanding why calling `thwart(num)` repeatedly is enough to result in the correct solution. (I.e. why is it able to find the SMALLEST number and doesnt just spit out any number divisible by the numbers 1-20?)
I only had some vague thoughts when programming it and was surprised at how quickly it worked. But now I have trouble figuring out why exactly it even works... The optimized solutions of other people on SO Ive found so far were all talking about prime factors which I can't see how that would fit with my program...?
Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: So you're asking how your own solution works? Can you try and specify what it is about your own solution that you don't understand?

Comment: your solution is trivial. You don't have to code anything to show that 20! is divisible by all numbers below 20. The question is whether a smaller one exists. So you have to change the for x in range(1,21): num *= x and search more candidates

Comment: and it works quickly because it only checks 20 numbers..

Comment: @Ev. Kounis I only start with num=20! Because this is the smallest easily computable number which is divisible by 1-20. This isnt the answer the program spits out though (from what ive gathered from other QandAs on this problem, the result is correct, namely 232792560)

Comment: @Michael That's not what the problem is about though. You have to find the smallest one. For example 10! is 3628800 but the smallest number divisible by 1,...,10 is 2520. Get my point? And you don't start with 20! btw. You end up with it

Comment: @Ev. Kounls I do get your point. But when i run the program it prints the correct solution (232792560.0) instead of 20! (which is a lot larger). My question is: why does the program give the correct result (smallest number divisible by 1-20) instead of another number divisible by 1-20 which is NOT the smallest.

Comment: @Michael Because you are lucky and it just so happens that the smallest such number is a factorial of something. Which is not the case with 2520 (=7! / 2). Your code will not work for 10. Try replacing all 21s with 11s and you will see.

Comment: @Ev. Kounis You may be right that im lucky but it also works for the "test case" (i.e. 1-10, Ive just tried it), so i think its unlikely that this works out of pure luck...? Thats not to say you may not have point - if you can find a number for which it doesnt work, i would be glad to see it (bc this would be more in tune with my intuition that my progrma should spit out some number divisible by 1-20, not nessecarily the smallest one).

Comment: @Michael You are correct. It does indeed. Whats happening is that you start from a value that is surely divisible by all the numbers (20!, you could also go for 20!/10! which also works) and you divide it by 2. If it still is acceptable, you try dividing by 3. If it no longer is, you divide by 2 again. This process, continues until it can no longer be divided by 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this isn't really a coding issue but a mathematical issue. If you look at all the numbers from 1-20 as the prime sthat make them you'll get the following:
1, 2,3,2^2,5,2^3,7,2^3....2^2*5. 
the interesting part here is that once you multiply by the highest exponent of every single factor in these numbers you will get a number that can be divided by each of the numbers between one and twenty.
Once you realize that the problem is a simple mathematical one and approach it as such you can use this basic code:

```
import math
primes = [2]
for n in range(3,21): #get primes between 1 and 20
    for i in primes:
        if n in primes:
            break
        if n%i == 0:
            break
        if i> math.sqrt(n):
            primes.append(n)
            break
s = 1
for i in primes:
    for j in range(10): # no reason for 10, could as well be 5 because 2^5 >20
        if i**j > 20:
            s = s*(i**(j-1))
            break

print s
```

Additionally, the hint that the number 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by all numbers should make you understand how 2520 is chosen:
I have taken a photo for you:
[image]
As you can caculate, when you take the biggest exponents and multiply them you get the number 2520.

**What your solution does**
your solution basically takes the number which is 1*2*3*4..*20 and tries dividing it by every number between 2 to 20 in such a way that it will still remain relevant. By running it over and over you remove the un-needed numbers from it. early on it will remove all the unnecessary 2's by dividing by 2, returning the number and then being called again and divided by 2 again. Once all the two's have been eliminated it will eliminate all the threes, once all the unnecessary threes will be eliminated it will try dividing by 4 and it will se it wont work, continue to 5, 6, 7... and when it finishes the loop without being able to divide it will raise a TypeError and you will finish your program with the correct number. This is not an efficient way to solve this problem but it will work with small numbers.

Comment: Hmm ive tried to run your code but it gives a wrong result (465585120)?

Comment: Just need to remove the * 2. print s

Comment: my bad, understood evenly divisible as any time you divide it it returns an even number, I will correct the answer immediately

Comment: It doesnt show me the photo for some reason - what is it a photo of? (Ok thanks)

Comment: The photo shows how the calculation is done to get to 2520, showing the prime factors of each of the numbers between 1 and 10 and mentioning which has the biggest exponent of the prime

Comment: Ok it runs and gives me the correct solution now. So does my program do the same as yours (find the unique prime factors with the highest power and multiply them) 'in reverse'?? I have found solutions similiar to yours (i.e. working with the prime factors) but still fail to see how they relate to my solution...

Comment: Id appreciate if you can mark this problem as solved

Comment: Thanks you have answered my question :) but could you please explain in what way my solution is "not an effective way"? Also, would a more effective way be to divide it in the reverse order (i.e. first try to divide by 20 as often as possible, then by 19 etc.)?